How can I fix a scuffed (presumably) laquered doorframe?
A metal hanger has scuffed / scratched the shiny paint on the doorframe - see pictures. Is there a way of touching up the paint easily and neatly, or at least hide a bit the damage? If so, what kind of paint should I look for? Thank you very much. 

A bit of light sanding and cleaning.  Any decent interior paint should do.  The problem is matching the finish and colour if doing a small section.
